# Where did secpol.msc and gpedit.msc disappear in Windows 8.1?

Tags: group-policy

`secpol.msc` and `gpedit.msc` were my favourite tools to deal with Local Security Policy and Group Policy respectively.

But after I updated my system to Windows 8.1, I'm noticing both of these are unavailable directories.

So, how in the world do I edit Local Security Policy and Group Policy in Windows 8.1? Do they now exist at all?

Answer (score -1):

Unfortunately secpol.msc and gpedit.msc have been removed from the Windows 8.1 base version and they are only available in the Pro or Enterprise version of Windows 8.1

https://social.technet.microsoft.com/forums/windows/en-US/ba2c852b-e777-4c96-8826-7bd958e787e1/gpeditmsc-and-secpolmsc-are-not-exist-in-windows-8